# Convert c++ function to PHP?

Tags: php, c++

I would like to convert my xor function to PHP. Can it be done? It needs to work as it`s working now...

```
string encryptDecrypt(string toEncrypt) {
    char key[9] = { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };
    string output = toEncrypt;
    for (int i = 0; i < toEncrypt.size(); i++)
        output[i] = toEncrypt[i] ^ key[i % (sizeof(key) / sizeof(char))];

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what is happening in the function?

Comment: what can happen in a XOR function ? -_- i am encrypting texts in my files...

Comment: I don't know what a XOR function is, and I'm not familiar with C++. Could you explain exactly what is happening so that we can understand how to replicate it in PHP?

Comment: i know php well, i just don`t know if any c++ code can be converted. as for you ( because almost everyone knows the old-age xor ), look at this article: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/38516/

Comment: No mate it`s not any aggression, it`s a simple question where thousands of coders are, and as short as i can be it seems like besides getting an answer, all i get is text(s) edit and - reputation, so what can i say...

Comment: SO isn't the place to get your code converted, hire a free lancer or try another forum / place where this might be accepted.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a coding studio. People are **helping** each other but they don't solve each other's problems if they even didn't try to do it themselves. It's not how it works like. Try to solve it yourself and ask us for some help if you meet problems and you can't find answers in the references, documentation or somewhere else. That's exactly why you get - reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use almost the same syntax in PHP as your C++ function does:

```
function encryptDecrypt($toEncrypt)
{
    $key= array( '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' );
    $key_len = count($key);
    $output = $toEncrypt;
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($toEncrypt); $i++)
    {
       $output[$i] = $toEncrypt[$i] ^ $key[$i % $key_len];
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Online demo for C++ function: https://ideone.com/g9cpHJ

Online demo for PHP function: https://ideone.com/3prgd0

Comment: Now this is what i was talking about! Yeah! Thank you very much, only one more question, it doesn`t matter if i use chars like: "£!$£^£$&%& right?

Comment: do you want to use these chars as keys? if they are non ascii chars, you must make sure that your source is saved as UTF-8, but it should work.

Comment: Well a strange problem occured... if i put something like [MAIN] then some ini values, it will decrypt only [MA and the rest not, i think these are the issue: [] - any text works, numbers, but i need that so i can store ini values :(

Comment: @Patratel you should ask a new question referencing this one and describe this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP it's something like this:

```
function encryptDecrypt($toEncrypt){
    $key = array( '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' );
    $output = $toEncrypt;
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($toEncrypt); $i++)
        $output = pow( $toEncrypt[$i], $key[$i % count($key)]; );

    return $output; }
```

I hope to be fine.

Comment: Vezi ca nu ai declarat $i :)

Comment: sorry was my problem :D - mersi ! :)